# Are isospectral manifolds necessarily homeomorphic?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, isospectrality

It's known that there are pairs of closed Riemannian manifolds which are isospectral but not isometric. 
Is it known if there are closed Riemannian manifolds which are isospectral but not homeomorphic?
(By isospectral, I mean that the Laplace-Beltrami operator on functions has the same spectrum on both manifolds.)

Thanks,

Dmitri

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's an example due to Doyle and Rossetti ("Tetra and Didi, the cosmic spectral twins"; http://arxiv.org/abs/math.DG/0407422) of 3-manifolds that are isospectral but not even homeomorphic.  I don't know if this was the first such example.

Comment: There's older examples, e.g. of Vigneras: 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=584073


Comment: Sunada (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=782558) gave a general framework in which the results of Vigneras fit.

Comment: Today I learned that you can't hear the topology of a drum.

Comment: Agol, are you sure, that Vigneras constructs isospectral varieties that are not *homeomorphic*, as opposed as only not isometric? I haven't read the paper in details, but the mathscinet reviews, the introduction of the paper, and the last theorem (theorem 8) says 
"isometric".



Comment: @Joel: For hyperbolic manifolds of dimension $>2$ homonorphism implies isometry (Mostow Rigidity). 

Comment: @Jan: It follows from an argument of Chen ( http://www.ams.org.proxy.lib.umich.edu/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1184007&loc=fromreflist ) that Vigneras' examples cannot be constructed from Sunada's method.

Comment: @BenLinowitz: Thanks, I didn't realize this. I was just going by the MR abstract, where it seemed that Vigneras construction had the same flavor, i.e. constructing non-conjugate subgroups which lead to isospectral manifolds, but apparently it is more more subtle and I was too hasty.